# Android inapp purchase is not showing payment method

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am working in android inapp purchase. According to documentation and my previous experience 2nd picture must let the user continue further payment steps. But whats wrong with this. Please help .TIA. first picture [image: ][1]]

[image: second picture after clicking continue button]

second picture after clicking continue button

Comment: Is this for every country? In-app is not available for all countries

Comment: I am in Bangladesh. But I tested it before. Is it  changed now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. This is area constrain. Previously Google play used to expose payment option in all over the world but not now. It is now available where google play gives their service available. Even we can't buy any paid app from google play in Bangladesh. This is not feeling good.